# import / export в Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Возник небольшой момент непонимания в плане импорта - экспорта в вебпаке.
В моём представлении, если я импортирую какой-либо фрагмент кода в условный index.js, то у этого импортирующегося фрагмента будет доступ к тем переменным, которые находятся в index.js.

Ведь вроде бы import - export это просто красивая оболочка require и анонимных самовызывающихся функций и там по логике у них, через замыкания, должен быть доступ ко всему. Но на практике, у тех самых "импортируемых" фрагментов кода, доступа к тому месту, куда они импортировались, они не получают.

Comment: Код модуля должен иметь доступ только к глобальным переменным, насколько я знаю

Comment: Да, вот подтверждение: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#module-environment . Я, правда, не знаю, насколько точно это эмулируется вебпаком, но, по крайней мере так оно *должно быть*, чтобы модулю были доступны только переменные из глобального для этого модуля скопа.

Comment: @smellyshovel, пока что при чтении документации на английском языке ощущаю себя не особо комфортно, но всё же нашёл статью где ответ на мой вопрос тоже даётся (https://habr.com/ru/company/nixsolutions/blog/261141/)